# java.lang.IllegalAccessError using org.apache.commons.cli when calling CommandLineParser#parser

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons-cli

I'm trying to use the Apache Commons CLI library to parse command line options in an Eclipse project, roughly following the examples in their [Usage Scenarios](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)

I added the `commons-cli-1.3.1` folder to the `lib` folder in the root of the Eclipse project.

I added this to my imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;
```

And this to the top of my `main`:

```
    Options options = new Options();
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = null;
    try {
        cmd = parser.parse( options, args);
    } catch ( ParseException e1 ) {
        System.err.println( "Unable to parse command-line options: "+e1.getMessage() );
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It compiles without error, but when it runs the `parser.parse` call generates this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.commons.cli.Options.getOptionGroups()Ljava/util/Collection; from class org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
```

I am not using any class loaders at this point.

**What does this error mean?  How can I resolve the error and parse the arguments?**

Comment: What is the value of args?

Comment: `args` is the parameter passed to `main`.  I'm not sure what args I've run it with, it may have started with a directory path, It's definitely been empty, and I just tried with typing random strings.  The error has been the same every time.

Comment: I don't think it can be done (or is a good idea) to use commons-cli for any arbitrary arguments. AFIK it is meant to provide a set of predefined arguments and validate them.

Answer (score 7):

**This is the most probably a dependency problem.**

It happens when you compile your code agains one version of the library (1.3.1 in your case) and then run with the older version of this library in your classpath.

I came across exactly this problem today when I had dependecy on commons-cli-1.3.1, but I had commons-cli-1.2 in my classpath (because I used yarn jar to launch my application)

**What you should do?**

1. You can just try downgrading to 1.2 as suggested above (this helped me)
2. Review your classpath and search for another version of commons-cli

**What does your exception message really mean?**
It means that some code at runtime tries to call some method which it has no right to call. For example, this could be trying to call a private method. Usually this is caught during compilation.

But if, for example, your code tries to call some function which is public in 1.3.1, but was private in 1.2. And if you compiled agains 1.3.1 but trying to launch with 1.2 in the classpath you will get that kind of error.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: I can see how this might be the case if I downloaded the library to use with something else distributed as class files, but I downloaded the library to use with my own code.  I've only ever had one version of the library on my computer; I don't see how eclipse could have compiled my code with one version of the library, and then run it with another.

Comment: @Polyergic I myself also installed only one version of this library. But Hadoop installed another one and added it to the classpath. So just make sure. Remember that when you are compiling java code against some library the library code itself is not stored in your jar. More over there is no runtime info regarding the version you compiled against.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the commons-cli to handle the command line parameters of my game [OpenPatrician](https://sourceforge.net/p/openpatrician/). Basically there are three parts to it. The definition of the allowed command line arguments:

```
Options opts = new Options();
opts.addOption(HELP_OPTION, "help", false, "Display help");
opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt(VERSION_OPTION)
        .withDescription("Version of this application")
        .create());
opts.addOption(FULLSCREEN_MODE, "fullscreen", false, "fullscreen mode");
opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName(WINDOWED_MODE)
        .withLongOpt("windowed")
        .hasOptionalArgs(1)
        .withArgName("widthxheight")
        .withDescription("Windowed mode with optional definition of window size like: 1280x780")
        .create());
opts.addOption(GAME_LOCALE, "lang", true, "Specify the locale to use");
opts.addOption(CLIENT_OPTION, "client", false, "Start application in client mode. Currently unused. Either client or server must be specified");
opts.addOption(SERVER_OPTION, "server", false, "Start application in server mode. Currently unused. Either client or server must be specified");
```

Providing a help message with all the possible parameters:

```
public void printHelp(Options options) {
    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
    formatter.printHelp( "OpenPatrician", options );
}
```

And of course the parsing of the arguments:

```
public CommandLine parseCommandLine(Options options, String[] args) {
    try {
        // parse the command line arguments
        CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
        return parser.parse( options, args );
    }
    catch( ParseException exp ) {
        printHelp(options);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parsing of command line arguments failed", exp);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using a PosixPaser here and not the default parser. So that might have different behaviour.

Comment: The documentation says PosixParser is "Deprecated since 1.3, use the DefaultParser instead", and Eclipse complains about it.  However, if I switch to PosixParser, I get a different error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: If you switch to DefaultParser, do you get the same error I get?

Comment: Well my code uses version 1.2 so maybe I should update ;)